# How to remove multiple (key,value) entries from a Python List - Ordered Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to remove multiple keys from a list ordered dictionary without any success.

The data structure I loaded from a file is shown below:

```py
[OrderedDict([('name', 'pageshift'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'bigdata'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'freeze'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'spark'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'dataupdate'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'django'), ('value', ''), ('activity', 'insert'), ('host_name', False), ('db_name', True)])]
```

When I am trying to delete some of the keys from the list of ordered dictionaries, it gives me an error:

```py
for key in ('value','activity','db_name'):
    del jdata[key]
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers,not str
```

Comment: You must iterate through the list and for each item (ordered dictionary) iterate through your key tuple and delete each.

Comment: You aren't _trying to delete some of the keys from the list ordered dictionary_, you're deleting  list elements. `jdata` is a list, look carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating a list of `OrderedDict` is nothing different from a list of normal dictionary. You can do:

```
for d in jdata:
    for key in ('value', 'activity', 'db_name'):
        del d[key]
```